# Spire-agent issue while deploying on kubernetes environment

Tags: kubernetes

I have deployed spire server and spire agents in my local environment. Spire-server and spire agent on master node are running fine but sipre-agents in worker nodes are not running. Can anybody please help me with this

Error:Warning  BackOff    111s (x28 over 10m)  kubelet, k8workerg1w1  Back-off restarting failed container

Comment: Please provide more details. It is very difficult to analyse based on what you have presented so far.

Comment: Seems your containers are unable to come up. This could be for many reasons like insufficient resources or security constraints. Try doing a `kubectl describe` of the deployment/replicaset and individual pods and look for events at the very bottom. Also, do a `kubectl get events` and look for any errors.

Comment: Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From                   Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----                   -------
  Normal   Killing    57m (x10 over 89m)    kubelet, k8masterg1m1  Container spire-agent failed liv                                      eness probe, will be restarted
  Warning  BackOff    12m (x128 over 68m)   kubelet, k8masterg1m1  Back-off restarting failed conta                                      iner
  Warning  Unhealthy  2m42s (x60 over 91m)  kubelet, k8masterg1m1  Liveness probe failed: Agent is

Comment: now it started running after creating PV for this and the apire-agent pod keeps on restarting and in events i could find there is livenessprobe error, but i dont see any with my livessprobe.

Comment: daemonset.yaml

livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - /opt/spire/bin/spire-agent
                - healthcheck
                - -socketPath
                - /run/spire/sockets/agent.sock
            failureThreshold: 2
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            periodSeconds: 60
            timeoutSeconds: 3

Comment: @bunny Could you please edit you question with that info and the actual exact problem?